# Modify and Combine Array of Objects by ID

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have the following array of objects:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "price": 22,
        "from": "00:00:00",
        "to": "02:00:00"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "price": 23,
        "from": "02:00:00",
        "to": "04:00:00"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "price": 10,
        "from": "04:00:00",
        "to": "1.00:00:00"
    }
]
```

I need to restructure it, so it combines the objects by ID, and creates a new nested array of objects:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "prices": [
            {
                "price": 22,
                "from": "00:00:00",
                "to": "02:00:00"
            },
            {
                "price": 23,
                "from": "02:00:00",
                "to": "04:00:00"
            },
        ]
    }
    {
        "id": 2,
        "prices": [
            {
                "price": 10,
                "from": "04:00:00",
                "to": "1.00:00:00"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Is there a simple way to do this? I'm getting lost in split, forEach and maps. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use a `Map` to collect the prices per id. First associate an empty prices list for each id, then iterate the data to populate those arrays, and finally extract the `Map` values to get the result:

```js
const data = [{"id": 1,"price": 22,"from": "00:00:00","to": "02:00:00"},{"id": 1,"price": 23,"from": "02:00:00","to": "04:00:00"},{"id": 2,"price": 10,"from": "04:00:00","to": "1.00:00:00"}];

const map = new Map(data.map(({id}) => [id, { id, prices: [] }]));
for (const {id, ...rest} of data) map.get(id).prices.push(rest);
const result = [...map.values()];

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Grouping by hash can save you from calling `.find()` or `.findIndex()`

```js
const data=[{id:1,price:22,from:"00:00:00",to:"02:00:00"},{id:1,price:23,from:"02:00:00",to:"04:00:00"},{id:2,price:10,from:"04:00:00",to:"1.00:00:00"}];

const result = Object.values(data.reduce((acc, { id, ...rest }) => {
    acc[id] ??= { id, prices: [] };
    acc[id].prices.push(rest);
    return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an easy way using [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
const input = [
  {
    id: 1,
    price: 22,
    from: "00:00:00",
    to: "02:00:00",
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    price: 23,
    from: "02:00:00",
    to: "04:00:00",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    price: 10,
    from: "04:00:00",
    to: "1.00:00:00",
  },
];

const output = input.reduce((nested, cur) => {
  const objWithoutId = (({id, ...o}) => o)(cur);
  if (!nested[cur.id]) {
    nested[cur.id] = {
      id: cur.id,
      prices: [objWithoutId]
    };
  }
  else nested[cur.id].prices.push(objWithoutId);
  return nested;
}, {});

console.log(Object.values(output));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

#### Explanation

We loop over the input using a JavaScript object. For every object we check it's ID. When we don't have that ID stored in our object already we create a new object containing the `id` and a `prices` array as well as the current value (without the `id` property). If we have encountered the same `id` already we already just need to push the current value (without the `id` property) to the already existing array.

Since we only have one loop and the lookups take `O(1)` time this algorithm takes `O(n)` to give a valid result.

Using this one-liner

```js
const objWithoutId = (({id, ...o}) => o)(cur);
```

we create a new object which contains all properties except `id`.

Lat but not least we just need to get the values of the created JavaScript object using [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values). Instead of a JavaScript object you could also use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to perform the equivalent algorithm with the same runtime properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method with [Array.findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to convert your data.

```js
const data = [{
    "id": 1,
    "price": 22,
    "from": "00:00:00",
    "to": "02:00:00"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "price": 23,
    "from": "02:00:00",
    "to": "04:00:00"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "price": 10,
    "from": "04:00:00",
    "to": "1.00:00:00"
  }
];

const transformedData = data.reduce((acc, item) => {
  const priceData = {
    price: item.price,
    to: item.to,
    from: item.from,
  };

  const index = acc.findIndex(({
    id
  }) => id === item.id);
  if (index === -1) {
    return [
      ...acc,
      {
        id: item.id,
        prices: [
          priceData
        ]
      },
    ];
  } else {
    acc[index].prices.push(priceData);
    return acc;
  }
}, []);

console.log(transformedData);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const items = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "price": 22,
        "from": "00:00:00",
        "to": "02:00:00"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "price": 23,
        "from": "02:00:00",
        "to": "04:00:00"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "price": 10,
        "from": "04:00:00",
        "to": "1.00:00:00"
    }
]

const result = items
.map(i => i.id)
.filter((item, pos, self) => self.indexOf(item) == pos)
.map( i => ({
  id : i, 
  prices : items
            .filter(item => item.id === i)
            .map(({ price, from, to}) => ({price, from , to}) )
    }) )
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) methods as follows:

```js
const input = [ { "id": 1, "price": 22, "from": "00:00:00", "to": "02:00:00" }, { "id": 1, "price": 23, "from": "02:00:00", "to": "04:00:00" }, { "id": 2, "price": 10, "from": "04:00:00", "to": "1.00:00:00" } ],

      output = Object.entries(input.reduce(
          (acc, {id,...rest}) =>
          ({...acc, [id]: [...(acc[id] || []), rest]}), {}
      ))
      .map(([id, prices]) => ({id,prices}));
      
console.log( output );
```